# CakePHP find all generates SQL that returns duplicate records (with same ID). Find list does not

Tags: mysql, cakephp

So, this code below:

```
    $friends = $this->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.id' => 102
            ),
            'contain' => 'Profile'
        )
    );
```

Generates this SQL:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`sForceId`, `User`.`householdId`, 
`User`.`householdSForceId`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`primaryUser`, `User`.`password`, 
`User`.`firstName`, `User`.`lastName`, `User`.`dateOfBirth`, `User`.`email`,   
`User`.`preferredEmail`, `User`.`phone`, `User`.`preferredPhone`, `User`.`homePhone`,
`User`.`workPhone`, `User`.`mobilePhone`, `User`.`ethnicity`, `User`.`ethnicityOther`,
`User`.`religion`, `User`.`religionOther`, `User`.`active`, `User`.`adminStatus`, 
`User`.`group`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `Profile`.`id`, 
`Profile`.`userId`, `Profile`.`aboutMe`, `Profile`.`picture`, `Profile`.`created`, 
`Profile`.`modified`, `Profile`.`lat`, `Profile`.`lng` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN
`profiles` AS `Profile` ON (`Profile`.`userId` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`id` = (102)
```

(apologies if reading that makes your brain hurt)

This SQL code selects the same record three times.  I have no idea why.  What's wrong with it?  More importantly, how do I change my CakePHP code to select that record one time instead of three times?

In case it's helpful: User belongsTo Household and hasOne Profile.

Comment: Do you have more than one profile attached to that user? I'd check the database manually `SELECT * FROM profiles where profiles.userId = 102`. If you have more than one, then the join will return 3 rows and therefore create three records in the array.

Comment: Brilliant! Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped you figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you somehow end up having more than one Profile for that User, you'll end up with multiple records due to the `LEFT JOIN` returning a record for each profile.

This applies to hasOne and belongsTo relationships as they are the ones that use `LEFT JOIN`s to join the data.

You can check for this by looking at the database manually: `SELECT * FROM profiles where profiles.userId = 102`